# How to call the constructor via. require? "require(module)(CONSTRUCTOR)"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

following problem:

I want to call my constructor like this:

```
var object = require('module')([params]);
```

module code:

```
function FunctionName(param) {
     function body..
}

exports = module.exports = FunctionName;
```

but when I'll do this, `object`is null (undefined).

Hoping for help :D Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://ide.c9.io/yeiniel/require-oo) the solution. Basically you need to call the constructor using `new`. In the example code on the previous link i enclose the `require('./module')` call in parenthesis so it is evaluated before new is called.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. This is working good, but is it also possible to call it without the `new` keyword? like [socket.io](http://socket.io) is doing it.?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you have to instrument the constructor function to detect when it is called without new and perform an inner constructor call in the constructor. See the updated code example for more info. If this is the solution to you problem please mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Works how I expected, thank you m8.